# How to make adjustable svg on browser resize

Tags: svg

I have created a shape with svg but when resize the browser it gets croped. If any knows the solution please answer.

```
<svg width="1315" height="65" id="intro-weg" style="background: red"> 
    <g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,611.25)"> 
        <g transform="scale(0.1,0.1)"> 
            <path d="m 10520,4376 c -383.8,320.87 -877.97,514 -1417.32,514 0,0 526.42,-552.76 -2211.03,-552.76 L 0,4337.24 0,0 l 10520,0 0,4376" class="colorize"></path>
        </g> 
    </g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps to make your SVG responsive:

1. Remove hardcoded `width`, `height` attributes from your svg element.

   ```
   <svg id="intro-weg" style="background: red">
   ```
2. Add `viewBox` attribute, specifying the required width and height (same as you specified for your svg earlier) as the 3rd and 4th values respectively: ([more about viewBox](http://jonibologna.com/svg-viewbox-and-viewport/))

   ```
   <svg id="intro-weg" viewBox="0 0 1315 65" style="background: red">
   ```
3. Specify width and height for your svg element in css:

   ```
   svg#intro-weg{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
   ```

Your svg should be responsive now.

Answer (score 1):

You have told the browser that this SVG is to behave as an image that is exactly 1315 pixels wide and 65 pixels tall.  Instead, consider removing the explicit `width` and `height` attributes, utilizing the `viewBox` attribute to define the exact dimensions of the internal SVG image, and placing the SVG image within your page using CSS.

That XML looks like it was created within a program (rather than by hand), so I'd first look for a "View Box" option somewhere in the program.  If you're typing this SVG XML out by hand, then consider reading [MDN's discussion of the viewBox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).